# Apple WeatherKit does not return data

Tags: swift, weatherkit

Trying to get weather data for a specific location and specific timezone.
EDITS:
Based on suggestions provided, I called WeatherService like this:

```
func getWeatherServiceData(requestId: String,
             latitude: Double,
             longitude: Double,
                     completion: @escaping (Bool) -> () ) async{
    
    
    
    var hourlyForecast = HourlyForecast()
    var hourlyWeather = HourlyWeather(hourlyForecast: [hourlyForecast])
    
    var dailyForecast = DailyForecast()
    var dailyWeather = DailyWeather(dailyForecast: [dailyForecast])

    
    let weatherService = WeatherService()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let weather = try! await weatherService.weather(for: location)
    let temperature = weather.currentWeather.temperature
    let uvIndex = weather.currentWeather.uvIndex
    let cnt = weather.hourlyForecast.count
    for hourlyForecast in weather.hourlyForecast {
        var hourly = HourlyForecast()
        hourly.temp = hourlyForecast.temperature.converted(to: .fahrenheit).value
        hourly.pressure = hourlyForecast.pressure.converted(to: .bars).value
        hourly.date = hourlyForecast.date
        hourlyWeather.hourlyForecast.append(hourly)
    }
    
    for dailyForecast in weather.dailyForecast {
        var daily = DailyForecast()
        daily.tempHigh = dailyForecast.highTemperature.converted(to: .fahrenheit).value
        daily.tempLow = dailyForecast.lowTemperature.converted(to: .fahrenheit).value
        daily.date = dailyForecast.date
        daily.dayOfWeek = dailyForecast.date.dayOfWeek()
        daily.precipitation = dailyForecast.precipitationAmount.converted(to: .inches).value
        
        dailyWeather.dailyForecast.append(daily)
    }
```

when I call this line:

```
let weather = try! await weatherService.weather(for: location)
```

I get error:

```
Thread 23: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=WeatherDaemon.WDSJWTAuthenticatorServiceListener.Errors Code=2 "(null)"
encountered an error when fetching weather data subset; location=<+29.92889404,-95.60774752> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 3/14/24, 11:21:14 AM Central Daylight Time,  error=WeatherDaemon.WDSJWTAuthenticatorServiceListener.Errors 2 Error Domain=WeatherDaemon.WDSJWTAuthenticatorServiceListener.Errors Code=2 "(null)"
```

Comment: 403 is usually a permissions error, I would check your JWT but what not just use `WeatherKit`? Is you token signed? If so, remember that your private key should never go to the client side.

Comment: From jwt.io, I input header, payload, private, and public key and generated JWT token. What do you mean by signing the jwt token? Do I need to process the jwt token I got from jwt.io? I already import WeatherKit and weatherkit is a part of the URL I sent - why are you saying use WeatherKit. I am still confused, any additional details would help

Comment: Jwt.iO will not give you a signed token, you need a signed token. The WeatherKit framework instead of REST. I suggest you watch “Meet WeatherKit”

Comment: REST WeatherKit is for server-side code so you can use your private key safely. REST WeatherKit isn’t for iOS/client side code.

Comment: @Lorem ipsum. Please see the edits to the original posting. I revised code and called WeatherServiceas suggested. I get error:Thread 23: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=WeatherDaemon.WDSJWTAuthenticatorServiceListener.Errors Code=2 "(null)"

Comment: Found my provisioning profile was invalid on the developer site. So I recreated new provisioning profile and downloaded. My Xcode has "Automatically manage signing". I ran code again and I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps on the developer website to make sure your app is allowed to use weatherkit? It usually works about an hour after you complete all the steps.

Comment: followed the developer web site. Checked the identifier and it had weatherKit enabled, but I still got error. So I deleted the App Identifier, back to XCode turned off and on automatically managed signing. It says Xcode created the profiles, app IDs and certificates. Two problmes Now: 1) don't see identitifer/profile in the developer web site. I build the program and ran, (2) get same error: Encountered an error when fetching weather data subset; error=WeatherDaemon.WDSJWTAuthenticatorServiceListener.Errors 2 Error Domain=WeatherDaemon.WDSJWTAuthenticatorServiceListener.Errors Code=2 "(null)"

Comment: I also get this error: Failed to generate jwt token for: com.apple.weatherkit.authservice with error: Error Domain=WeatherDaemon.WDSJWTAuthenticatorServiceListener.Errors Code=2 "(null)"

Comment: The configuration steps, there is more that needs to be done than just adding an entitlement.

Comment: Followed all the steps of WWDC video and developer website. Created an Identifier with WeatherKit, , accepted notification, created provisioning profile, imported profile into Xcode, added WeatherKit capability to the Xcode. Deleted profile, re-created twice, and imported. The only difference between the steps outlined in WWDC video and mine is that that I am adding WeatherKit to an existing project and not a new one. I don’t know what steps I am missing.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/help/account/configure-app-services/weatherkit/ Look at step 4. You should always look at the documentation first.

Comment: Yes I missed adding WeatherKit to Service tab completely, my mistake. It works now. Thank you.